# Typescript: Pass by value or by reference

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this file:

object.ts:

```
export const myObject {
    prop1: "prop1",
    prop2: "prop2",
    ...
    ...
}
```

and I have this class

my-class.ts

```
export class MyClass {
    private obj: any;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.obj = obj
    }
}
```

and I have this file:

main.ts

```
import { myObject } from "object";
import { MyClass } from "my-class";


let class1 = new MyClass(myObject);
let class2 = new MyClass(myObject);
let class3 = new MyClass(myObject);
```

will creating instances of the class `MyClass` this way pass the object `myObject` by value or reference. In another way, will the `myObject` object be copied three times; I'm concerned about the memory.

**UDPATE**

Consider this other example:

my-class.ts

```
export class MyClass {
    private obj: any;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.obj = obj
    }
    getValue(str: string) {
        return obj[str];
    }
}
```

function1.ts

```
import { myObject } from "object";

let myClass = new MyClass(myObject)

export function fn1(str: string) {
    return myClass.getValue(str);
}
```

function2.ts

```
import { myObject } from "object";

let myClass = new MyClass(myObject)

export function fn2(str: string) {
    return myClass.getValue(str);
}
```

main.ts

```
import { fn1 } from "function1";
import { fn2 } from "function2";

console.log(fn1(str));
console.log(fn2(str));
```

Will the second example create two copies of `myObject`?

Comment: I'm going to assume it has the same [evaluation strategy as Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)

Comment: It is by reference. And yes, this is a JavaScript question. Not TypeScript.

Comment: @unional can you please check my updated question?

Comment: Still the same instance.

Comment: @unional how come the same instance, I'm importing it twice so that would create it twice, right?

Comment: It is cached. The resolution will resolve to the same executed module context (<- not official term).

Comment: @unional thanks I got it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first example, `myObject` will be created only once, since argument is passed by reference (or the pointers to objects are passed by value).

For your second example, there is nothing changed about JavaScript's evaluation strategy, so `myObject` will be still the same instance. But if you look at the compiled JavaScript code then you will find that function1.ts and function2.ts will be wrapped in two different functions, which makes `myClass` become two different variables.